# EntityFramework - Querying data with IQueryable/IEnumerable - "An operation is already in progress" error happens only with Npgsql.EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable, npgsql, iqueryable

“An operation is already in progress”: Issue with data access with EntityFramework5.Npgsql for EF 5.
Although same code for data access works perfectly for oracle.

Why is this error received on iterating over an IEnumerable? I think this should not be the case, as for IEnumerables, the data has been loaded already in memory.

Also it is received when executing a where on IQueryable. How can we use new DbContext connection to filter/iterate over Iqueryable/IEnumerable multiple times without getting this error?

Or is there any one time configuration we can use to use new DbContext for each operation on IQueryable/IEnumerable?

i dont want to change code since same piece of code works perfectly for oracle. i am making a db agnostic application

this is my code:

```
private IEnumerable<AuditListView> GetAuditList(string user = "", string entity = "", string module = "", string action = "", string start = "",
                                                         string end = "", string parentAuditLogId = "")
    {
        try
        {
            LoginBL loginBL = new LoginBL(LogCategory.Default);
            var list = _objBL.LoadAuditList(user, entity.Replace(" ", ""), module.Replace(" ", ""), action, start, end, parentAuditLogId).OrderByDescending(a => a.Item1.LogDateTime)?.ToList(); ;

            List<AuditListView> sublist = new List<AuditListView>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var view = new AuditListView();
                view.LogId = item.Item1.AuditLogId.ToString();
                view.Date = item.Item1.LogDateTime;
                view.Time = item.Item1.LogDateTime;
                view.Activity = item.Item1.ActionId;
                view.Module = item.Item1.ModuleId.PascalCaseToSentence();
                view.Description = item.Item1.Message;
                view.EntityType = item.Item1.EntityId.PascalCaseToSentence();
                view.EntityName = item.Item1.EntityValue;
                view.User = item.Item1.UserName;
                view.IsDetailsAvailable = item.Item2;
                view.IP = (loginBL.getIPBySessionID(item.Item1.SessionId) != null) ? loginBL.getIPBySessionID(item.Item1.SessionId) : (item.Item1.IPAddress != null) ? item.Item1.IPAddress : "N/A";
                view.ChannelId = (item.Item1.ChannelId != 0) ? Convert.ToString(item.Item1.ChannelId) : "N/A";
                view.IsChildAvailable = (item.Item1.ChildEntries.Count > 0) ? true : false;
                sublist.Add(view);
            }

            return sublist;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception handling
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**LoadAuditList function:**

```
        public IEnumerable<Tuple<AuditLog, bool>> LoadAuditList(string user = "", string entity = "", string module = "", string action = "", string start = "", string end = "", string parentAuditLogId = "")
    {
        DateTime startDate = (start != "") ? DateTime.ParseExact(start, ConfigReader.DbDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : DateTime.Today;
        DateTime endDate = (end != "") ? DateTime.ParseExact(end, ConfigReader.DbDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : DateTime.Now;
        List<string> sessionIds = new List<string>();
        // Get all the audit entries
        IEnumerable<AuditLog> audit = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentAuditLogId))
        {
            // getting all the records having parent Id is null.
            audit = _entities.AuditLogs.Where(l => l.LogDateTime >= startDate && l.LogDateTime <= endDate &&
                                                                                                     l.ParentId == null);
        }
        else
        {
            // getting all the records having the given parent Id.
            decimal dParentAuditLogId = Convert.ToDecimal(parentAuditLogId);
            audit = _entities.AuditLogs.Where(p => p.ParentId == dParentAuditLogId);
        }


        // Apply filters according to the parameters

        if (user != "")
        {
            // Get the List of all the audit log entries that fall in the given sessions.
            audit = audit.Where(a => a.UserName != null && a.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower());
        }

        return audit.Select(a => Tuple.Create(a, a.AuditDetails.Any()));
    }
```

**Exception message:**
Stack trace:
04/01/2021 01:54:42 PM | Error | HexaValue : 0x12306370. DecimalValue : 305161072 ErrorMessage : An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.. ErrorInnerMessage : System.InvalidOperationException: **An operation is already in progress**. at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState) at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior). ErrorSource : System.Data.Entity. ErrorStack : at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() at System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) at System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item) at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AuditLog_70A94E5E6B9A45522EC41C28B81AED462515790101D2F7863A431EED685CB7F6.get_AuditDetails() at Models.AuditLog.BLL.AuditLogBL.<>c.<LoadAuditList>b__7_5(AuditLog a) in BLL\AuditLogBL.cs:line 155 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext() at Controllers.AuditLogController.GetAuditList(String user, String entity, String module, String action, String start, String end, String parentAuditLogId) in Controllers\AuditLogController.cs:line 115

**Further technical details**

- Npgsql version: 5
- PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 13.2
- Operating system: Windows 10

Comment: Need to see the code, and did you try ToList?

Comment: i dont want to change code since same piece of code works perfectly for oracle. i am making a db agnostic application.

Comment: OK sure, but still, showing the code would be helpful, as would to try using ToList which the normal get out for this problem, and would not effect the Oracle code unless the record set is large.

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't mean the data has already been loaded, IEnumerable is just an interface with some properties and methods defined. A lot of things inherit from IEnumerable, and you can downcast a lot of types to it - I wouldn't rely on thinking that was the case.

Comment: @mikelegg added code. Also using ToList everywhere in a large application is an overhead :) ... Y does Npgsql library behaves this way? Any idea?

Comment: At the networking level, there's just a TCP connection to PostgreSQL, and there's no way to have multiple queries running at the same time. It's possible to use cursors and to incrementally fetch results, but that involves more network roundtrips which are bad for perf. One possible thing Npgsql could do, is buffer the entire resultset to release the connection; but that increases memory requirements. Basically multiple active result sets (MARS) is a peculiar SQL Server feature which simply can't be supported (efficiently) by PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ShayRojansky thanks for clarifying, so what I feel is that even ORACLE supports MARS , is that correct ?... because same entity framework based data access code works OK for oracle and SQL server. But not PostgreSQL.

Comment: Could be that Oracle also supports MARS, I wouldn't know... But PostgreSQL doesn't...